# VSTS: Why are pipelines appear to be triggered by the same user?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a master release pipeline that deploys child pipelines and kicks them off. When running the master pipeline, Azure DevOps properly reports who launched that deployment and each deployment instance shows that it was triggered by by **different** users (i.e. whoever actually kicked it off).

However, when the child pipeline is created and run, it always displays the **same** user no matter who kicked off the master pipeline deployment. In other words, the child pipeline does not show the person who triggered the master deployment that created it.

To help illustrate, let's say I have Users A and B.

1. User A kicks off the master pipeline
2. Azure DevOps reports that User A deployed from master
3. Child pipeline is created and automatically run
4. Azure DevOps reports that User A deployed from the child

In this case, User A is correctly reported as the user who kicked off the child pipeline deployment. Now consider:

1. User B kicks off the master pipeline
2. Azure DevOps reports that User B deployed from master
3. Child pipeline is created and automatically run
4. Azure DevOps reports that **User A** deployed from the child

In the second case, User A is incorrectly reported as the one who kicked off the child pipeline deployment.

FWIW, The JSON used to generate the child pipeline was last modified by User A and User A's credentials are used for making Azure DevOps REST API calls, so those may have some influence. What is the cause of this issue and how can we solve it?

Comment: How do you kick off the child pipeline?

Comment: I think @daniel-mann has answered the question, but I want to test it first. We kick off the release using User A's credentials in the master pipeline, so that is likely the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind of answered your own question, at least in terms of the root cause:

> User A's credentials are used for making Azure DevOps REST API calls

If you're using someone's credentials to queue a build or release, then it's queued as that user's identity. There's no way around it.

Luckily, there is a system access token that you have access to during builds and releases, which should be sufficient for your purposes.

Instead of using a user identity to make REST API calls, use the `$(System.AccessToken)` variable. You'll have to allow scripts access to the token by checking the "Allow Scripts Access to OAuth Token" box in the phase settings.

This won't make the build be queued by User B, but it also won't be incorrectly displayed as the wrong person -- it will show up as a system service account.

You may want to reconsider your release approach -- consider having one release definition with multiple environments.

Comment: I think I may have answered my question, but my wording wasn't entirely clear. When we launch the child pipeline from the master, we call the REST API with User A's credentials to create the release, so that likely is the cause (need to test). The access token might be a better way to do this, so I will look into that more as well. BTW, we've discussed our needs with MS directly and they've recommended the approach that we're taking. Multiple environments will become unmanageable quickly.

Comment: Finally got around to testing this out and the access token does appear to be the way to go. Thanks for your answer!